# Get varray values as concatenated text list

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, oracle18c, varray

In db<>fiddle for Oracle 18c:

If I select a varray, then db<>fiddle returns an empty resultset, which is misleading.

```
with data as (select sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') as my_array from dual)
select my_array from data

Result:

MY_ARRAY
--------   [resultset is empty]
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=672ba91ae7265353f282ffd5cd80d958)

@JackDouglas said this in a related post:

> PHP’s [oci_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php) doesn’t like [abstract data types](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ADT) like
> SDO_GEOMETRY, I’m getting errors like this in the logs:
>
> ```
> PHP Warning:  oci_fetch_all(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT PHP 
> Warning:  oci_fetch_all(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT
> ```
>
> Source: [Return a value/row when selecting SDO_GEOMETRY](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=2008)

---

As a workaround, I want to return the varray's values as a **concatenated text list** (the same way it works in SQL Developer).

Like this:

```
with data as (select sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') as my_array from dual)
select varray_list(my_array) from data
--          ^^^ A fake function.

Result:

MY_ARRAY
--------   
SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c')
--or
'a', 'b', 'c'
--or 
a,b,c
```

---

Question:

In a query, is there a way to get a varray's values as a concatenated text list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LATERAL` join a table collection expression and then use `LISTAGG`:

```sql
with data (my_array) as (
  select sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') from dual union all
  select sys.odcivarchar2list('d', 'e') from dual
)
select s.my_array_str
from   data d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(column_value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
                  AS my_array_str
         FROM   TABLE(d.my_array)
       ) s
```

Which outputs:

> | MY_ARRAY_STR |
> | --- |
> | a,b,c |
> | d,e |

or, if you want the surrounding quotes:

```sql
with data (my_array) as (
  select sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b', 'c') from dual union all
  select sys.odcivarchar2list('d', 'e') from dual union all
  select sys.odcivarchar2list('f', NULL, 'g') from dual
)
select s.my_array_str
from   data d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(
                  '''' || column_value || '''',
                  ','
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM)
                  AS my_array_str
         FROM   TABLE(d.my_array)
       ) s
```

Which outputs:

> | MY_ARRAY_STR |
> | --- |
> | 'a','b','c' |
> | 'd','e' |
> | 'f','','g' |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a6596f44cc4f8b9c835da9bbfbcb320)*